# How to resolve?. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, exception, native

Hi I have added the native libraries to my project but I am getting exception as. 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries.** 
I have added the native libraries like this.

```
Right click on the Project.
Select Properties.
Click on RUN.
In VM Options TYPE -Djava.library.path="[dir]".
Press Ok.
```

In NEATBEANS IDE

my method is like this.

```
static{
//         System.out.println("inside the static intializer");
        System.loadLibrary("SBXPCJavaProxy");
//        System.load("D:\\bio-metric\\SBXPC_CORE_130330\\SBXPCJavaProxy.dll");
    }
```

I added like this.

```
-Djava.library.path="D:\bio-metric\SBXPC_CORE_130330"
```

Comment: could anyone please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try and add the library somewhere inside the project path, like a /lib folder maybe. And load the library from there.